# Use other Liferay Services in a Service Hook

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am writing a wrapper to `JournalArticleLocalService` in a Liferay hook plugin. The goal I am trying to achieve is to persist the `priority` field of the asset, which is currently hardcoded to be set to `null`.

I need to use the `AssetEntryLocalService`. I tried this:

```
public class MyJournalArticleLocalServiceImpl extends
    JournalArticleLocalServiceWrapper {

@BeanReference(type = AssetEntryLocalService.class)
protected AssetEntryLocalService assetEntryLocalService;
```

When the overwritten method is called, the reference is not set.

What do I need to do such that the reference is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directly `AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil`, it not fast as the reference `assetEntryLocalService` but it works.

I think the reference could not be set in the way you want.